# Dynamic SQL to execute large number of rows from a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a very large number of rows which I wish to execute via dynamic SQL. They are basically existence checks and insert statements and I want to migrate data from one production database to another - we are merging transactional data. I am trying to find the optimal way to execute the rows.

I've been finding the coalesce method for appending all the rows to one another to not be efficient for this particularly when the number of rows executed at a time is greater than ~100.

Assume the structure of the source table is something arbitrary like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[DataField1] [int] NOT NULL,
[FK_ID1] [int] NOT NULL,
[LotsMoreFields] [NVARCHAR] (MAX),
CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FK1]
(
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [int] NOT NULL, -- Unique constrained value
CONSTRAINT [PK_FK1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
```

The other requirement is I am tracking the source table PK vs the target PK and whether an insert occurred or whether I have already migrated that row to the target. To do this, I'm tracking migrated rows in another table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChangeTracking]
(
[ReferenceID] BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1),
[Src_ID] BIGINT,
[Dest_ID] BIGINT,
[TableName] NVARCHAR(255),
CONSTRAINT [PK_ChangeTracking] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ReferenceID] ASC)
)
```

My existing method is executing some dynamic sql generated by a stored procedure. The stored proc does PK lookups as the source system has different PK values for table [dbo].[FK1].
E.g.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (<ignore this existence check for now>)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Dest].[dbo].[MyTable] ([DataField1],[FK_ID1],[LotsMoreFields]) VALUES (333,(SELECT [ID] FROM [Dest].[dbo].[FK1] WHERE [Name]=N'ValueFoundInSource'),N'LotsMoreValues');
    INSERT INTO [Dest].[dbo].[ChangeTracking] ([Src_ID],[Dest_ID],[TableName]) VALUES (666,SCOPE_IDENTITY(),N'MyTable'); --666 is the PK in [Src].[dbo].[MyTable] for this inserted row
END
```

So when you have a million of these, it isn't quick.

Is there a recommended performant way of doing this?

Comment: Are  you trying to insert or update rows depending if the rows are already there? Are you looking to see how to use the merge statement?

Comment: How many rows will you execute at once?

Comment: @RBarryYoung with coalesce I found around 100-1000 at a time was the sweet spot. The size of the batch is entirely performance driven though so whatever is fastest.

Comment: We are supposed to know what coalesce means.

Comment: You should show us your current code and some (small) example data and results.  The "*coalesce method*" you are alluding to is not at all clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, the MERGE statement works well when you're looking at a complex JOIN condition (if any of these fields are different, update the record to match). You can also look into creating a HASHBYTES hash of the entire record to quickly find differences between source and target tables, though that can also be time-consuming on very large data sets.

Comment: I have a simple existence check like if not exists(<SomeUniqueConstraintValue>) INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (...) VALUES (<SomeUniqueConstraintValue>,....) There might be over a million such records and checks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're making these updates like a front-end developer, by checking each row for a match and then doing the insert. It will be far more efficient to do the inserts with a single query. Below is an example that looks for names that are in the tblNewClient table, but not in the tblClient table:

```
INSERT INTO tblClient
        ( [Name] ,
          TypeID ,
          ParentID 
          )
SELECT nc.[Name] ,
    nc.TypeID ,
    nc.ParentID
FROM tblNewClient nc
    LEFT JOIN tblClient cl
        ON nc.[Name] = cl.[Name]
WHERE cl.ID IS NULL;
```

This is will *way* more efficient than doing it RBAR (row by agonizing row).

Comment: Interesting idea. I forgot to add my secondary requirement so I would have to also have to work out how to satisfy tracking the source vs destination PK mappings with this style of query.

Comment: So in the example above, could you add a [Source] column to tblClient, and in the SELECT statement include [Source] = 'tblNewClient'?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the two answers from @RusselFox and putting them together, I reached this tentative solution (but looking a LOT more efficient):

```
MERGE INTO [Dest].[dbo].[MyTable] [MT_D]
USING (SELECT [MT_S].[ID] as [SrcID],[MT_S].[DataField1],[FK_1_D].[ID] as [FK_ID1],[MT_S].[LotsMoreFields]
FROM [Src].[dbo].[MyTable] [MT_S]
JOIN [Src].[dbo].[FK_1] ON [MT_S].[FK_ID1] = [FK_1].[ID]
JOIN [Dest].[dbo].[FK_1] [FK_1_D] ON [FK_1].[Name] = [FK_1_D].[Name]
) [SRC] ON 1 = 0 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT([DataField1],[FL_ID1],[LotsMoreFields])
VALUES ([DataField1],[FL_ID1],[LotsMoreFields])
OUTPUT [SRC].[SrcID],INSERTED.[ID],0,N'MyTable' INTO [Dest].[dbo].[ChangeTracking]([Src_ID],[Dest_ID],[AlreadyExists],[TableName]);
```